# Библиотека для отображения данных из sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

Подскажите библиотеку для табличного отображения данных, максимально по виду и функционалу приближенную к `DBGrid` из Delphi или Майкрософтовским `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 3):

используйте `TableLayout`

---

вот пример

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fistname_et_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="firstName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastname_et_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="lastname" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addmem_btn_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

управлять таблицой (MainActivity.java)

```
package com.pavan.sqlitetabledemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TableLayout table_layout;
 EditText firstname_et, lastname_et;
 Button addmem_btn;

 SQLController sqlcon;

 ProgressDialog PD;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  sqlcon = new SQLController(this);

  firstname_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fistname_et_id);
  lastname_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname_et_id);
  addmem_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addmem_btn_id);
  table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

  BuildTable();

  addmem_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    new MyAsync().execute();

   }
  });

 }

 private void BuildTable() {

  sqlcon.open();
  Cursor c = sqlcon.readEntry();

  int rows = c.getCount();
  int cols = c.getColumnCount();

  c.moveToFirst();

  // outer for loop
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

   TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
   row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   // inner for loop
   for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextSize(18);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);

    tv.setText(c.getString(j));

    row.addView(tv);

   }

   c.moveToNext();

   table_layout.addView(row);

  }
  sqlcon.close();
 }

 private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {

   super.onPreExecute();

   table_layout.removeAllViews();

   PD = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
   PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
   PD.setMessage("Loading...");
   PD.setCancelable(false);
   PD.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

   String firstname = firstname_et.getText().toString();
   String lastname = lastname_et.getText().toString();

   // inserting data
   sqlcon.open();
   sqlcon.insertData(firstname, lastname);
   // BuildTable();
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   BuildTable();
   PD.dismiss();
  }
 }

}
```

[Полный код тут](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/01/android-loading-sqlite-data-tablelayout.html)

[исходники тут SQLiteTableDemo.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qn1i75euzn1k33a/SQLiteTableDemo.zip)